# How to download "ceres-solver-2.1.0.tar.gz" file to install Ceres solver in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, ceres-solver

I am following the tutorial to install Ceres solver here "http://ceres-solver.org/installation.html".

Once I installed the necessary auxiliary libraries we are to execute the following line

> tar zxf ceres-solver-2.1.0.tar.gz

What is the command to download the correct version of ceres solver so that I can proceed with the installation?

With best,
Azmyin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, modifying the instructions posted here
https://brucknem.github.io/posts/install-ceres-solver/

> wget http://ceres-solver.org/ceres-solver-2.1.0.tar.gz

Hope this helps someone.

With best,
Azmyin